# Postgresql Sqlalchemy dynamic table partition creation issue

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, table-partitioning

I'm using postgresql and python sqllachmey for creating the partitioned table. Below is the example code.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import Text
Base = declarative_base()
class Students(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Students"

    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    type = Column(Text)
    desc = Column(Text)
    creation_time = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = {
        'postgresql_partition_by': 'RANGE (creation_time)'
    }
table_list = [Students.__table__]
Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine, tables=table_list)
```

The above code creates a paritioned table and i'm creating the partitions using pg_partman extension.

Now, my need is that I want to use the class 'Students' for creating the student table under different databases, and some databases don't need the partitioned table. How can I make the above code dynamic so that I can take out 'postgresql_partition_by' from **table_args**?

According to the documents, it looks like, I have to use dictionary for table column definition but I'm not quite sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

The [keyword arguemnts of `Table`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.**kw) (or `__table_args__`) are dialect specific, so your `postgresql_partition_by` will only be used with `postgresql` dialects, not `sqlite` or others.

> ##### class sqlalchemy.schema.Table(*args, **kw)
>
> [...]
>
> **kw – Additional keyword arguments not mentioned above are dialect specific, and passed in the form `<dialectname>_<argname>`. See the documentation regarding an individual dialect at [Dialects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/index.html) for detail on documented arguments.

Comment: All the databases are postgresql. It is just that there are different PostgreSQL servers and all of them can't have partitioning for some reason. I'm sorry,  i didn't mention it earlier

Comment: How do you plan on discriminating between servers which can and cannot have partitioning ?