# Dynamic partitioning with sqlalchemy and alembic

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-partitioning, alembic

I have a question and sqlalchemy/alembic documentation has not provided me much insight.

Is is possible to create alembic migration script that creates postgres partitioning of a certain table in database?

For example partition by timestamp. I want to run script one a month that will create new partition once a month. At the begining I have only one table, after a month it will be partitioned into two tables, and so on...

This post gave me an idea [SO-partitioning-LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75223934/postgresql-sqlalchemy-dynamic-table-partition-creation-issue) .
Here it uses Sqlalchemy, but these are not migrations, these are scripts that I need to manually insert timestamps If I got that right
[Git-discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5313#issuecomment-931332837)

Comment: Not sure, what you expect from `alembic`, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75250267/4808122) is described the migration using plain PostgreSQL

Comment: Cool, but the idea is when new month comes, all the rows with "new month timestamp" should be inserted into that new partition. Basically a script needs to check for datetime and create new partition if neccesary